# What are the main benefict from using backbone.js?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, backbone.js

I was wondering if backbone.js was only an MVC architecture? What are the main advantage of using it over AngularJs and such ?

Comment: why not read the docs to see what backbone does?

Comment: Don't worry, I did, but I am not sure to understand the advantage of using it instead of others MVC, fair question in my opinion

Comment: if you read it... would have realized you are comparing client side to server side... apples to oranges

Comment: Well, I know alot about server side MVC, but not much about client-side, and I am wondering what are the main features that makes it strong... I don't see what you don't understand

Comment: Pretty much the same things that make it strong on the server side, but principally, the constructs to easily separate your view and data logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

backbone.js is *client side* MVC.  You can (and probably should) use backbone.js *along with* a server side framwork.

backbone.js is useful anywhere you wish to build fairly intricate singe page applications.

I would also recomend checking out [backbone-marionette.js](http://marionettejs.com/) once you have gotten a feel for backbone.js.

Comment: Ohh so basicaly it's not a framework on himself, its a way to structure your javascript in any project, is that's it ?

Comment: @YannChabot Exactly... It's definitely worth taking the time to learn if your interested in building a single page application.  Also, consider building with [Coffee](http://coffeescript.org/), compiles to javascript and is sooo much less of a headache to read!